# Unexpected token react map()

Tags: reactjs

**Getting error at ConsultantlistItem in react jsx syntax **

```
 return this.props.userList.map(function(n,index){
                debugger
                 <ConsultantListItem key={index} {...n}/>

             });
```

But when i use lodash

```
_.map(this.props.userList,function(userList,index)
  { <ConsultantListItem key={index} {...userList} />  });
```

working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The return statement must be inside the map function. This is what you are doing wrong. Try this

```
{this.props.userList.map(function(n,index){
            return 
             <ConsultantListItem key={index} {...n}/>

         });}
```

Comment: the map function must return something. yours isn't returning anything. rather you are returning the map function. Try it once.